# CreateJS/EaselJS multi stage and touch enable

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs

Im using 30 canvas in the dom , and using createjs nextstage property to relay clicks to my lower canvases, but stagemousemove is not firing only in IOS devices

kindly help

```
for (var k = 0; k < currentArray.length; k++) {
    if (k != 0)
        currentArray[k].nextStage = currentArray[k - 1]
    createjs.Touch.enable(currentArray[k])
}

for (var i = 0; i < currentArray.length; i++) {
    currentArray[i].addEventListener("stagemousedown", _this.startDraw);
}

this.startDraw = function (evt) {
    var nc = evt.target;
    nc.addEventListener("stagemousemove", _this.draw);
    nc.addEventListener("stagemouseup", _this.endDraw);
}
```

stagemousemove is not working in most of the canvases,it works if i remove the nextstage property

Comment: Please show the code you have tried. Also expand the question a little more so it's understandable...

Comment: Why are you using 30 canvas/stages? Is there a reason you can't add things to the same canvas? A bunch of separate canvases could be less performant instead of more performant.

Comment: whatever i draw on the center canvas should update on the other canvas .   i tried with one whole canvas calling stage update is very heavy, so ill have 30 canvas and update one canvas and use drawimage to update others.